# Galois extension $\frac{\mathbb Z_2[x]}{\langle 1+x+x^3 \rangle}:\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $\frac{\mathbb Z_2[x]}{\langle 1+x+x^3 \rangle}:\mathbb Z_2$ be a extension.

Is it a Galois extension? Is it a normal extension?

**Solution:**

Let's see if it is a Galois extension. We have that $[\mathbb Z_2[x]/\langle 1+x+x^3 \rangle:\mathbb Z_2]=3$. Elements of the field are of the form $a(1+I)+b(x+I)+c(x^2+I)$ where $I = \langle 1 + x + x^3 \rangle$ and $a, b, c \in \mathbb Z_2$

Now let $T\in G(\mathbb Z_2[x]/\langle 1+x+x^3 \rangle:\mathbb Z_2)$. Then $$T(a(1+I)+b(x+I)+c(x^2+I))=a(1+I)+bT(x+I)+c(T(x+I))^2. $$
Therefore $T$ will be completely determined if we know what is $T(x+I)$.

I know that $\alpha_1=x+I$ is a root of $p(x)=1+x+x^3,$ and I'd like to find another 2 roots to then conclude that $G(\mathbb Z_2[x]/\langle 1+x+x^3 \rangle:\mathbb Z_2)$ has only 3 elements.

How to find the other 2 roots?

Also is there a similar method to test if the extension is normal?

Comment: I don't know how you defined things but Galois = normal + separable and since $\mathbf{Z}_2$ is perfect, all finite extensions over it are separable.

Comment: @T.Gunn I wanted to use this theorem: Let $K:F$ finite. Then $K:F$ is Galois iff $[K:F]=oG(K:F)$, to test if it is a Galois extension.

Comment: @T.Gunn my professor defined a Galois group of $K:F$ as the set of functions $f$ such that f is $F-$homomorphism and $f: K:F\to K:F$ is also invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a general structure theorem to finite fields.

> **Theorem 1**: A field has $p^n$ elements if and only if it is the splitting field of $x^{p^n} - x$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$.

It follows from Theorem 1 that all finite extensions of finite fields are normal.

> **Theorem 2**: The Galois group of $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}/\mathbf{F}_p$ is generated by the Frobenius automorphism $\sigma : x \mapsto x^p$.

Now let us pretend we haven't proved this yet. We can still use the theorem. Here's how:

Let $\mathbf{F}_2[\alpha]$ be an extension of $\mathbf{F}_2$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $1 + x + x^3$. We know the roots of $1 + x + x^3$ are going to be generated by applying to $\alpha$, all Galois automorphisms of the normal closure of $\mathbf{F}_2[\alpha]$. Now by cheating and using Theorem 2. We "guess" that the roots are $\alpha, \alpha^2 = \sigma(\alpha)$ and $\alpha^4 = \sigma^2(\alpha)$. Now let's prove this.

Note that
\begin{align}
 0 &= (1 + \alpha + \alpha^3)^2 = 1^2 + \alpha^2 + (\alpha^2)^3 \\
 0 &= (1 + \alpha + \alpha^3)^4 = 1^4 + \alpha^4 + (\alpha^4)^3
\end{align}
using the result that $(x + y)^p = x^p + y^p$ in characteristic $p$. Hence, as claimed, $$1 + x + x^3 = (x - \alpha)(x - \alpha^2)(x - \alpha^4).$$

Therefore $\mathbf{F}_2[\alpha]/\mathbf{F}_2$ is normal (it is the splitting field of $1 + x + x^3$) and $\mathbf{F}_2[\alpha]/\mathbf{F}_2$ is Galois (its Galois group is $\{\operatorname{id}, \sigma, \sigma^2\}$).

Comment: I dont understand your notation, where is this '< >' ? is it equivalent to what in your notation?

Comment: @Annelise $\alpha = x + \langle 1 + x + x^3 \rangle$

Comment: Which are the explicit elements of $\frac{\mathbb Z_2[x]}{\langle 1+x+x^3 \rangle}?$. I know there are 8 elements.

Comment: @Annelise The elements are $0, 1, \alpha, 1 + \alpha, \alpha^2, 1 + \alpha^2, \alpha + \alpha^2, 1 + \alpha + \alpha^2$, where again $\alpha = x + \langle 1 + x + x^3 \rangle$. Since $1 + \alpha + \alpha^3 = 0$ you have $\alpha^3 = -(1 + \alpha) = 1 + \alpha$ (since $1 = -1 \pmod 2$) so all powers $\alpha^n$ with $n \ge 3$ can be written with smaller powers of $\alpha$.

Comment: There must be a 'trick' or something like that to guess the roots, in the example were  $\alpha ,\alpha^2,\alpha^4$.But in general, what is it?

Comment: @Annelise That's the trick. If $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbf{Z}_p$ and $r$ is a root of $f$ then the roots of $f$ are $r, r^p, r^{p^2}, r^{p^3}, \dots$.

Comment: oh ok, I have another similar exercise and I had this polynomial $p(x)=2+x^3$ in $\mathbb Z_7$ and it is irreducible. But the roots were proposed as $\alpha_1=x+<>,\alpha_2=2x+<>,\alpha_3=4x+<>$. This is a different case then?

Comment: In that case, for example, $\alpha_1^7 = \alpha_1(\alpha_1^3)^2 = \alpha_1(5)^2 = 4\alpha_1$ (since of course $\alpha_1^3 = -2 = 5$).

Comment: Also another trick that was used is $\alpha^3 = -(1 + \alpha) = 1 + \alpha$. So in general it is a good idea to write $\alpha^n=...$ to simplify expressions?

Comment: Sometimes. If you do that you would get $\alpha^4 = \alpha^2 + \alpha$. One can make an argument that actually $\alpha^4$ is simpler. But if your goal is to lower the powers as much as possible, that's how you do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61963/discussion-between-annelise-toft-and-t-gunn).

Comment: Talking back about this problem, I proposed the galois group as you did,     $\{\operatorname{id}, \sigma, \sigma^2\}=\{x+I,x^2+I,x^4+I\}$, where $I = \langle 1 + x + x^3 \rangle$. But my professor told me to reduce the last term.why should I reduce it? Is it wrong if it is not reduced?

Comment: @AnneliseToft You know how $\mathbf{Q}[\sqrt 2] = \{a + b \sqrt2 : a, b \in \mathbf{Q}\}$? Every element of $\mathbf{F}_2[\alpha]$ (where $\alpha^3 + \alpha + 1 = 0$) can be written as $a + b\alpha + c\alpha^2$ with $a, b, c \in \mathbf{F}_2$. Some people prefer to write everything in this form. If we replace $2$ by $19$  then we would have $\alpha, \alpha^{19}, \alpha^{361}$. Now we might be okay with $\alpha^4$ but $\alpha^{361}$ looks a bit odd. So over $\mathbf{F}_{19}$, reducing seems to be the way to go. So applying this logic fairly, one should reduce over $\mathbf{F}_2$ as well.

Comment: The best option would be to just give both forms. I.e. say $\alpha^4$ and $\alpha + \alpha^2$.

Comment: okay..so is my answer for the galois group correct?

Comment: $\{\operatorname{id}, \sigma, \sigma^2\}$ is the Galois group, $\{x + I, x^2 + I, x^4 + I = x + x^2 + I\}$ are the roots of $X^3 + X + 1$.

Comment: Yes, I was confused because of this $\sigma =\alpha^2=x^2+I$

Comment: @AnneliseToft $\sigma(\alpha) = \alpha^2$ not $\sigma = \alpha^2$.

Comment: Do you remember the trick? If $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbf Z_p$ and $r$ is a root of $f(x),$ then the roots of $f$ are $r, r^p, r^{p^2}, r^{p^3}, \dots$. But for the Galois group we only use $\{\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^4 \}$ why did you stop on $\alpha^4?,$ could be $\alpha^8$ too?

Comment: @Anne $\alpha^8$ is also a root but $\alpha^8 = \alpha$.

Comment: oh ok so the roots begin to repeat between them, i.e. $\alpha^{16}=\alpha^2?$

Comment: @Anne yes, exactly